# Can Hyperledger Composer transactions support third-party javascript libraries/node.js packages?

Tags: javascript, hyperledger-composer

Is it possible to include other javascript libraries/functions and/or even node.js packages in Composer transaction functions/logic?

Examples:

1. To use another HTTP library like axios to implement GET/PUT/DELETE and other HTTP methods that are not available yet
2. Check a signature we can use the crypto2 node.js library.

Answer (score 0):

As of now I don't believe that is possible. See [Can I use JavaScript libs with require on transaction processor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44688828/can-i-use-javascript-libs-with-require-on-transaction-processor)

I have been using node-red along with the node-red-contrib-composer tie in:

> https://medium.com/@CazChurchUk/integrate-your-blockchain-with-anything-using-hyperledger-composer-and-nodered-4226676f7e54

to call external services and send HTTP requests that are not possible using the post() function that is supported in the transaction processor

> https://hyperledger.github.io/composer/integrating/call-out.html

Answer (score 0):

add the javascript library to the lib folder of your business model . Then use them in the transaction 'logic.js'  without import or require, since it will be injected later in the application .

### [image]

### [image]

### **Here the result in composer playground**

[image]

### **here the result in composer-rest-server**

[image]

Happy coding ...

**[Medium Story](https://medium.com/@tarek.lejmi/hyperledger-fabric-use-javascript-libraires-on-transaction-processor-33e13b8c020d)** : https://medium.com/@tarek.lejmi/hyperledger-fabric-use-javascript-libraires-on-transaction-processor-33e13b8c020d