# Function in logic.js works in playground but not in REST server

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger, hyperledger-composer

I have a function in my logic.js file that retrieves the latitude and longitude of a plane from an api:

```
function getLocation(){

    var url = 'https://opensky-network.org/api/states/all?time=1458564121&icao24=3c6444'

    return fetch(url)             // Call the fetch function passing the url of the API as a parameter
    .then(function(resp){
        data = resp.json()         // Transform the data into json
        return data
    }).then(function(data) {

        lat = data.states[0][5]
        long = data.states[0][6]
        lat = lat.toString()
        long = long.toString()
        location = [lat,long]
        return location
      })
    }
}
```

when I test this function on the playground it successfully retrieves the latitude and longitude of the plane. However when I try to carry out the same function through the composer REST sever I get the following error:

> Error trying invoke business network. Error: No valid responses from any peers.\nResponse from attempted peer comms was an error: Error: chaincode error (status: 500, message: ReferenceError: identifier 'fetch' undefined)

Does anyone know why this is the case?

Comment: Does your server block requests to that URL in anyway?

Comment: No, I don't think so. If I put the url into my browser I can see the JSON object returned.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

think `fetch()` is a web browser (library) API, especially if using the web connection with a 'fake' fabric in Playground - whereas its not available in the Composer REST server / runtime looks like (when the transaction in question that calls the function is invoked).

Hyperledger Composer allows you to do call-outs - see more here https://hyperledger.github.io/composer/integrating/call-out

the OpenSky REST APIs can be called from there (and the results returned as JS Objects if possible)

eg.   GET /states/all example

```
var url = "https://opensky-network.org/api/states/all?time=1458564121&icao24=3c6444";

return post( url, postTransaction)
  .then(function (resp) {
// same code as you had before
});
```

The body property of the response (resp) is automatically converted to a JS Object if possible, otherwise it is returned as a string.

Comment: Yeah, it has me stumped, Do you know any way to get around this Paul?

Comment: Thanks a mill Paul :)

Comment: Hey Paul, I'm just having a bit of difficulty implementing this. If I'm doing a GET request to the OpenSky API, why do I have to pass the Parameter postTransaction? and if so what data should it contain?