# Include external library file in Hyperledger Composer

Tags: hyperledger, hyperledger-composer

Is there a way to include an external library in Hyperledger Composer? I would like to use [this library](http://numeraljs.com/) for currency computations. I saw in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44688828/can-i-use-javascript-libs-with-require-on-transaction-processor) (`which I think is old and there might be advancements on this since the response is 9 months old`) that at the time it was not possible to include external libraries in Hyperledger

Answer (score 0):

If you are referring to business network Transaction Processor functions (which I think you are) then you cannot use require to include an external library. Other people have used things like Webpack to build a monolithic package of javascript to get around this limitation but I don't know the details on that or how practical it is from both an operational and supportable point of view.